# Sort Two Dimensional Array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, iphone, sorting

```
var financeArray = [[Any]]()

//some code here to populate financeArray

print("financeArray:\(financeArray)")
```

Result:

```
[["VF009", 416052.545002.62],
 ["VF003", 318095.705914636],
 ["B005", 142228.01838465 5],
 ["VF010", 198340.167128308],
 ["VF002", 467586.9413639],
 ["VF001", 9347271404463.13],
 ["B002", 142546.55683996],
 ["VF011", 443370.11349.86],
 ["VF008", 92280.41684],
 ["VF012", 367211.3614995],
 ["VF004", 392188.90705226.39],
 ["VF007", 179616.3264362.1],
 ["VF006", 462121.40585729457.33],
 ["VF005", 151343.09298267]]
```

I need to sort this array by the codes that start with VF. I've searched the internet and found some solutions but I usually get the error down below.

```
Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Any' operands
```

Desired outcome is:

```
[["B002", 142546.55683996],
["B005", 142228.01838465 5],
["VF001", 9347271404463.13],
["VF002", 467586.9413639],
["VF003", 318095.705914636],
["VF004", 392188.90705226.39],
["VF005", 151343.09298267],
["VF006", 462121.40585729457.33],
["VF007", 179616.3264362.1],
["VF008", 92280.41684],
["VF009", 416052.545002.62],
["VF010", 198340.167128308],
["VF011", 443370.11349.86],
["VF012", 367211.3614995]]
```

Comment: so what about codes starting with B ?

Comment: Make your life easier getting rid of your arrays of `[Any]` and create of structures with `code: String` and `value: Double` properties

Comment: codes starting with B letters are irrelevant because once I achieve to sort the array it  will do in that order: "special characters, alpha numeric chars and numbers"


I know I have to use structures but API I use is totally pain in the arse. API returns Integer when there is no data but returns String when there is a data.

and this was the last thing I tried: 

let sortedArr = financeArray.sorted(by: {$0.first < $1.first})

Comment: The error says it pretty much itself, your type of your data is "Any" and you cant use the binary operator on it. You should convert it to some comparable type, and then it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because Binary operator '<' is not able to be applied to two 'Any' because you are comparing two values that < does not know how and what to compare.

so type casting to desired type is necessary

```
var financeArray = [[Any]]()
 financeArray = [["VF009", "416052.545002"],["VF003", "318095.705914636"],["B005", "142228.01838465"],["VF010", "198340.167128308"],["VF002", "467586.9413639"],["VF001", "9347271404463.13"],["B002", "142546.55683996"]]

let sortedArray  = financeArray.sorted(by: {($0[0] as! String) < ($1[0] as! String) })
print(sortedArray) //results = [["B002", "142546.55683996"], ["B005", "142228.01838465"], ["VF001", "9347271404463.13"], ["VF002", "467586.9413639"], ["VF003", "318095.705914636"], ["VF009", "416052.545002"], ["VF010", "198340.167128308"]]
```

Comment: I knew that I should convert Any to String but I didn't know where to use "as! String" Being Junior without a Senior is exhausting, I can't believe I missed that point. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: This will crash if there is any sub array that it is empty or that its first element is not a String

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you properly should define a structure of your data, so it does not rely on an array of `Any`. As your error says, the compiler does not know how to compare when something is of type `Any`. Now, i do not understand how your data works, so let me just show you how sorting is done with a made up example.

Let us say, we have some data based on the following data structure:

```
struct Product {
    let title: String
    let price: Double
}
```

and lets just create some data:

```
let products = [
    Product(title: "Car", price: 12.5),
    Product(title: "Watch", price: 5.5)
]
```

now you are able to sort your products easily:

```
let sorted = products.sorted { $0.price < $1.price }
```

Here sorted in ascending price. Hope you see why structuring your data in a type-strong way, makes your code easier to work with.

Comment: I know this is the best solution but I have my own reasons to use Any, anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @OsmanTüfekçi There is no reason that would be good enough to use it. Btw `416052.545002.62` it is not a valid Double. Edit your question and add your real code